# GroovyClassloader Performance improvement in 1.7 to 2.0 relase

Tags: groovy

what are the performance improvement are done on Groovy1.7 to groovy 2.0-beta release, i working on the 1.7.2 release, need to upgrade to groovy 2.0 beta version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [Groovy 2.0 Beta 1 Release Notes](http://jira.codehaus.org/secure/ReleaseNote.jspa?projectId=10242&version=17925)
- [Groovy 2.0 Beta 2 Release Notes](http://jira.codehaus.org/secure/ReleaseNote.jspa?projectId=10242&version=18072)